# Bitbucket for Salesforce

Tags: deployment, git

I want to set up bitbucket so that i can push the code changes to the bitbucket and the changes should get deployed to the Salesforce org from bitbucket.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you done any research yet? Where did you get stuck? How can we help you get started?

Answer (score 1):

You might this project useful:

- [SFDX Bitbucket Pipelines Example](https://bitbucket.org/charlie_jonas/sfdx-pipelines-example/src/master/)

> This project is meant to demonstrate how bitbucket pipelines can be used in conjuction with Saleforce DX to provide a continuous integration solution.